# Iterate a collection then only one time execute stream concat all element of the collection

Tags: java, dynamic, collections, java-stream, concatenation

I have a `HashMap<String, List<User>>`
I want return a allList merge form all `List<User>` of the Hashmap. 
And with only one time trigger statement `Stream.concat(list1, Stream.concat(list2, Stream.concat(list3,Stream.concat(list4,...))))...`
My target is higher performance.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a single Stream of all the elements of all the `List<User>`s, you should use `flatMap`, not `Stream.concat`:

```
Stream<User> users = map.values().stream().flatMap(List::stream);
```

Then you can do any processing you require on that `Stream`. For example, create a `List` of all the `User`s:

```
List<User> userList = map.values()
                         .stream()
                         .flatMap(List::stream)
                         .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can perform a fold operation to `concat` all the list of users but this is an overkill, so instead go with the approach suggested in the other answer or simply:

```
List<User> accumulator = new ArrayList<>();
for (List<User> l : map.values()) 
     accumulator.addAll(l);
```